# Storing connection objects in session variable for database rollback

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jdbc, ojdbc

I have a web application spread across multiple modules in different JSP pages. Currently I use different oracle connection objects across these pages due to scope limitations. I now need to rollback database transactions done on any of the JSP pages in a central JSP display page on button click. But database rollback requires an associated connection object.

I thought of maintaining only one connection object, adding it to the list of session variables and dereferencing it when needed. By doing this, I can rollback database transactions done in any page from the central display page. Kindly let me know if the above is feasible.

Comment: What kind of server do you use and how do you manage the db connection?

Comment: I am using the Apache Tomcat server. I am using Oracle JDBC connection objects to open and close connections within the JSP file in this form: Connection conn = null;UpdateStmt = conn.createStatement();

Answer (score 0):

What I'd try is to create a singleton class that provides you the needed connection. I'd try a pool but if not, just a singleton would work somehow. When you ask for rollback, recover the connection from the class and do the rollback (or ask the class to do that for you). If you prefere a pool, then iterate over the active connections and do rollback.

Opening connections inside jsp is not very good idea. Try to isolate the logic from the pages as much as possible. Instantiating classes could be a small step to accomplish this.

Hope this helps.